# Not able to count the records and validate login in Ionic 3 and Angular

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an application where the user registers itself by providing it's email and password which is stored in `SQLite` DB. The user then tries to login into the app using the same email and password and gets redirected to home page after successful login.

I am not able to validate the user based on the email and password that is entered.
I am not sure how to parse the int returned after executing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE email=? AND password=? AND active='Y';` on the table.

**login.ts (Gets called on click of Login button)**

```
 doLogin(user: User) {
    //check if the record exits with the same email and password
    this.userProvider.validLogin(user.email, user.password)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Validated user successfully..." + data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
      });

    //navigate to next page now
    this.navCtrl.push(SetupPage)
      .then(() => console.log("Navigating to next page now..."))
      .catch((e) => console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(e)));
  }
```

**user.ts (UserProvider)**

```
validLogin(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log("Validate user login..." + email + ", " + password);
    return this.databaseProvider.getDatabase().then(database => {
      return database.executeSql(SQL_VALID_LOGIN, [email, password])
        .then((data) => {
          //SHOULD RETURN 1 ROW IF THE USER IS VALID, CURRENTLY RETURNING NaN
          //NOT SURE HOW TO PARSE THIS AND RETURN IT BACK 
          //WANT TO RETURN "TRUE" OR "FALSE"
          console.log("Executed Valid Login sql..." + parseInt(data));
        }).catch((e) => {
          console.error("Error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
        });
    });
  }
```

**Console Log:**

```
[app-scripts] [00:19:59]  console.log: Validate user login...ab@ab.com, 123456
[app-scripts] [00:19:59]  console.log: Executed Valid Login sql...NaN
[app-scripts] [00:19:59]  console.log: Validated user successfully...undefined
[app-scripts] [00:19:59]  console.log: Navigating to next page now...
```

Comment: Out of curiosity , why did you choose SQL on client side for this auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query always returns single row and single column data. Column name will be **COUNT(*)**. And you don't need to parse value to integer as it's already an integer.

change your validLogin to following.

```
validLogin(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log("Validate user login..." + email + ", " + password);
    return this.databaseProvider.getDatabase().then(database => {
      return database.executeSql(SQL_VALID_LOGIN, [email, password])
        .then((data) => {
          //SHOULD RETURN 1 ROW IF THE USER IS VALID, CURRENTLY RETURNING NaN
          //NOT SURE HOW TO PARSE THIS AND RETURN IT BACK 
          //WANT TO RETURN "TRUE" OR "FALSE"
          console.log("Executed Valid Login sql..." + data.item(0)['COUNT(*)']);
        }).catch((e) => {
          console.error("Error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: After trying the above solution this is what I see now in the console logs `app-scripts] [21:56:56]  console.log: Validate user login...a2@bc.com, 124456
[app-scripts] [21:56:56]  console.error: Error: 
[app-scripts] [21:56:56]  console.log: Executed Valid Login sql...undefined
[app-scripts]             {"__zone_symbol__currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}`